# Conditional creation of new dataframe column to display the content of existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and it reads below

```
SKU  ClosingBalance
S1       10
S2       np.nan
S3       0
S4       20
```

I want to create a new column which will display only the SKU's which have positive closing balance and rest should be marked as np.nan, like below

```
SKU      ClosingBalance    SKU_CB
S1       10                S1
S2       np.nan            np.nan
S3       0                 np.nan
S4       20                S4
```

I tried

```
conditions = [(df['ClosingBalance'] > 1)]
df['SKU_CB'] = np.select(conditions, df['SKU'], default=np.nan)
```

Not working. Need all your kind help.

Comment: Is it actually "np.nan" in your data or did you just put that for whatever reason, and it's actually NaN?

Comment: yeah it is actually NaN, I mentioned np.nan for some reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['SKU_CB'] = np.where(df['ClosingBalance'] > 1, df['SKU'], np.nan)
```

Alternatively, in your use of [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), you seem to have a problem with the second parameter:

> choicelist : list of ndarrays The list of arrays from which the output elements are taken. It has to be of the same length as condlist.

So it probably should be

```
df['SKU_CB'] = np.select(conditions, [df['SKU']], default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 3):

So your data *does* in fact contain numeric data with NaNs, so this will suffice—

#### `pd.Series.mask`/`where`

```
df['SKU_CB'] = df.SKU.where(df.ClosingBalance.gt(0))
```

Or,

```
df['SKU_CB'] = df.SKU.mask(~df.ClosingBalance.gt(0))
```

```
df
  SKU  ClosingBalance SKU_CB
0  S1            10.0     S1
1  S2             NaN    NaN
2  S3             0.0    NaN
3  S4            20.0     S4
```

---

If by chance, your data has NaN-ish values that aren't exactly NaN, then here's an alternative. Using `pd.to_numeric`, determine what values aren't valid, and use that to mask `SKU`.

#### `pd.to_numeric` with `pd.Series.mask`/`where`

```
df['SKU_CB'] = df.SKU.mask(
    ~pd.to_numeric(df.ClosingBalance, errors='coerce').gt(0)
)
```

Or,

```
df['SKU_CB'] = df.SKU.where(
   pd.to_numeric(df.ClosingBalance, errors='coerce').gt(0)
)
```

```
df
  SKU ClosingBalance SKU_CB
0  S1             10     S1
1  S2         np.nan    NaN
2  S3              0    NaN
3  S4             20     S4
```

Comment: @AmiTavory Does SO allow `<style>` tags? I think Google still has that CSS animation easter egg on the results when you search for `<blink>`…

Comment: @abarnert :-) I don't know.